# actions_intent_OPTION is not fired anymore by google assistant

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

We all know that we must declare an DialogFlow follow-up intent with event 'actions_intent_OPTION' in it to be fired by google assistant when an user tap on carousel or a list.
As showed by https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#list_and_carousel_option
askWithCarousel and askWithList give us the opportunity to fire such particular intent that returns that option data. Here a simple code that shows how to get it:

> const param = app.getContextArgument('actions_intent_option',    'OPTION').value;

This was true until yesterday, when something happened on google side.
I'm not the only one facing this strange issue, you can find others with the same problem on the new DialogFlow support forum:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dialogflow/IiugVkm1uIA;context-place=forum/dialogflow

Is there anybody with the same problem? Does anyone have a solution? 
(it's seems that the only solution is to create a new project with a new google ID from scratch but it's not feasible for me).

When i tap or say the right choise the actions_intent_OPTION intent is not fired, instead a simple text query is fired (witch can or not be catched by an intent).
This way of working is very frustrating: no support, no one to talk with on the official support forum (full of newbie, sigh), very difficult to debug due to firebase function logs available just on a dynamic web-page.
Does everybody has choosen the DIALOGFLOW ENTERPRISE EDITION to get some support?

Comment: We have found a bug and working on a fix.

Comment: thank you @LeonNicholls, waiting for news.

Comment: hi @LeonNicholls any update? I'm still stuck with the development of the app. Is there any workaround?

Comment: the bug seems fixed today. well done

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dialogflow, you need to create a dialogflow intent and in Event section, add `actions_intent_OPTION`

[image: screenshot - dialogflow]

and handle that dialogflow intent in the code.

```
app.intent('actions_intent_OPTION-handler', (conv, params, option) => {
//handler code goes here
})
```